# Upload video to server in android using volley

Tags: android, file-upload, android-volley, video-processing

I am trying to upload an image and video from my android application to a private server.

I can't figure out how to upload video with other images and text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a multipart request in Volley and specify the path of your photo/video that you want to upload. Follow this tutorial for a better understanding - http://www.techstricks.com/multipart-request-using-android-volley/